# Meaning of "they" in 'Wall-street loves to use confusing terms, to make you think only they can do what they do.'

Tags: word-usage

I'd like to make sure if I have right idea about this.
These lines are quote from a movie called "The Big Short" ([script](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=the-big-short)).

> It's pretty confusing right?
>
> Doesn't it make you feel bored...
>   Or stupid...
>
> Well... it's supposed to.
>
> Wall-street loves to use
>   confusing terms, to
>   make **you** think only **they**
>   can do what **they** do.

The **they** stands for people in general, doesn't it? so in this context **you** and **they** are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here  *they* refers to "Wall-street." And *wall-street* refers to the "the money market or the financiers of the U.S." ([dictionary dot com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wall-street)) or the

> collective name for **the financial and investment community**, which includes stock exchanges and large banks, brokerages, securities and underwriting firms, and big businesses.

([Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/w/wallstreet.asp), emphasis mine)

*You* here  means *people in general* but includes the person the guy  is talking to as a specific example.